# Changing color of text in a tkinter window by using colorchooser in python 3 and tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Try to choose the color of the then print it, the printing bit works just need to get the color part working. If you need to see more of the code just ask.

```
def mColour():
    color = colorchooser.askcolor()
    color_name = color[1]
    mlabel2 = Label(mGui,text=color).pack()
    messagebox.showinfo(title = "Colour",message = "This feature has not been fully added yet.")
    return
def mhello():
    mtext = ment.get()
    fg=color_name
    mlabel2 = Label(mGui,text=mtext).pack()
    return
```

Error:

```
color_name not defined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution with your help.

```
#colour chooser
def mColour():
    color = colorchooser.askcolor()
    color_name = color[1]
    mlabel2 = Label(mGui,text=color).pack()
    messagebox.showinfo(title = "Colour",message = "This feature has not been fully added yet.")
    return color_name
#printing message 
def mhello():
    mtext = ment.get()
    mlabel2 = Label(mGui,text=mtext, fg = mColour()) # i put the fg and the mcolour inside here insted.
    mlabel2.pack()
```

Answer (score 2):

From what I can tell, you are trying to access a variable that was created within the local scope of `mColour` (which means it isn't in `mhello`'s scope).  You can fix this by making `mColour` return `color_name`:

```
def mColour():
    color = colorchooser.askcolor()
    color_name = color[1]
    mlabel2 = Label(mGui,text=color).pack()
    messagebox.showinfo(title = "Colour",message = "This feature has not been fully added yet.")
    #################
    return color_name
    #################
```

And then accessing that value in `mhello` like so:

```
def mhello():
    mtext = ment.get()
    ############
    fg=mColour()
    ############
    mlabel2 = Label(mGui,text=mtext).pack()
```

Also, I would like to address two things:

1)  A bare `return` at the end of a function does nothing.

2)  The `pack` method returns `None`.  Your code should look like this:

```
mlabel2 = Label(mGui,text=mtext)
mlabel2.pack()
```

Now `mlabel2` points to the label like it should.

Comment: It now says myColor not defined

Comment: @Minigeek22 - You named the function `mColour`, not `myColor`.

Comment: It now just post the color code and the word i want to be printed but still black. ( Still )

Comment: The same problem is a curing it prints the color code and the word in black.